# objective c social/social.h not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, xcode5

```
//
//  Social.h
//  Social
//
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Social/SLServiceTypes.h>
#import <Social/SLRequest.h>
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import <Social/SLComposeViewController.h>
#endif
```

I am trying to compile a simple app for iOS-6 in Xcode 5, and calling the basic     Social framework provided by apple.  I am getting an error of SLComposeViewController - file not found.  This is a new error that just decided to show up at build time this afternoon.  I have the rest of the social framework.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but since its a framework provided by apple, you need to Link in the framework first, then import it.

So goto the Build Phases by clicking on your project in the file manager view, then clicking the Build Phases tab.
After youre in, click on link binary with libraries and hit the plus button

Then search for Social

This is just off the top of my head, i cant get on my mac now, but it should be the solution

Comment: Hello, The framework is linked and imported. This was working for several days then just stopped.  The file exists ad seems to be missing a symbolic link to the /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Headers where XCode is saying the file should be found - however it does not reside there - nor does a symlink to the actual file location which is actually:./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Headers/SLComposeViewController.h

Answer (score 0):

Sometime in the old version of Xcode this type of problem occure.For this problem goto link framework and library section , click on plus button and add "AdSupport.framework".then make a clean and build your project.