# I can't import <Social/Social.h> framework in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was adding framework then after I was try to import `<Social/Social.h>` in Xcode 6.4 Objective-C. But I can't import social framework. The error description is:

> lexical or preprocessor issue "Social/Social.h" not found

Comment: have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969153/4056108)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add "addsuport.franework" from linked framework and libraries in your Xcode. then after make clean,build project.it is working.